# Searching in array.indexOf(x) always return -1 even the value exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

```
var myarray = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"];

function myfunc(myvar)
{
  if ((myarray.indexOf(myvar) > -1)
  {
    alert(myvar);
  }
  else
  {
    alert(myarray.indexOf(myvar));
  }
}
```

where `myvar` is the value of input box of type "text". Alerting the return value gives me always -1. Any ideas? Browsers are FF 17.0.1 and Chrome 23.0.1271.97m

Comment: alert myvar and check if it is what you want it to be

Comment: What are you trying to do? It is not the way...

Comment: `mychannels.indexOf(myelem)` - what? `myelem` is undefined here.

Comment: Sorry, have a problem with keyboard. Already fixed it but still the same problem

Comment: Can you show not the function, but how it's called then? It's obviously nothing wrong with the source here.

Comment: 'If' closing bracket missing... Could you fix that too

Comment: @raina77ow sure: `<form onsubmit='myfunc(document.getElementById("searchbox").value); return false;'><input type="text" id="searchbox" /><input type="button" value="Search" onclick='myfunc(document.getElementById("searchbox").value);' /><form>`

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/AK2y6/

Comment: Can you add `console.log(myvar)` to this function (place it at the beginning)?

Comment: @A.V well still getting -1 :(

Comment: @raina77ow logs tells that: string1 , test.html(line 165)

Comment: Why it's `string1 `, with space? Don't you need to trim it first, as n my answer?

Comment: It's not, just put it while writting the answer

Comment: Check your code, looks like you blanked out the myarray.

Comment: Nope, this is the only code and the array is full. Checked with that:
`myarray.indexOf(myvar) + "\n" + myarray.length` which gives me -1 and 4

Comment: Truly strange, can you please copy all the code to jsfiddle.net. Don't worry even if it does not work.

Comment: @closure Not a problem - http://jsfiddle.net/5J2kv/ The strange thing is that it works sometimes, sometimes not :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firstly ran 100+ times. Not a single mishap on latest Chrome on Mac OSX.
2. I only saw inconsistent html tag. Fixed that.
3. I am assuming you are facing problem in IE. Added a meta tag for that.

Run http://jsfiddle.net/5J2kv/1/ and see if anything improves for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: Yep, but this is a small test scenario. And already noted that is tested only on FF and Chrome without using NoScript or similar addons ...  Unfortunately the same thing happens - works 3-4-5 times and then again -1 :( Just decided that using array for storing div ids is better than checking the whole DOM tree (idk if that's the correct term) every time. Anyway thanks for the help, but can you explain what means inconsistent html tag and which one :)  ps btw the real one app has array size of 27 and will grown maximum 2x times. if this matters ...

Answer (score 2):

#### Undefined variable

```
alert(mychannels.indexOf(myelem));
-------------------------^
```

You are getting the input in the function parameter as `myvar` but nowhere you have defined the `myelem`. That stops the script. BTW, what were you trying to do?

If it works, try replacing the code with:

```
alert(mychannels.indexOf(myvar));
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine.

Here's the live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qcu4x/).

```
var myarray = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"];

$('#myvar').live('change', function () { myfunc($(this).val());});

function myfunc(myvar)
{
  if (myarray.indexOf(myvar) > -1)
  {
    alert(myvar);
  }
  else
  {
    alert(myarray.indexOf(myvar));
  }
}​
```